# CSS replacement for <div align="center">

Tags: html, css, deprecated

I know this question has been asked many times, but I never saw a satisfactory answer. I mean, an answer that actually works.

So, here we go again. Take this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFMyn/3/

If you remove the `align="center"` from the HTML, what CSS do you need to use to make the result look the same as the original?

The answers I found usually amount to `margin:0 auto` and/or `text-align:center` but neither of those have the desired effect of making the result look the same as the original.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this please explain if they did it because they think the answer is too easy, if trying to find good alternatives for deprecated attributes is a waste of time, or something else? Maybe my English isn't good enough?

Comment: In the HTML5 spec, sections 10.2 and 10.3.3 address how browsers are expected to map `<div align="center">` to CSS. In short, it *is* mostly `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto` and `text-align: center`, but there are certain nuances.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The text align center covers most of the text elements but a little extra is needed to centre align the table

```
div {width:400px; text-align:center;}
table {margin: 0 auto;}
table td {text-align: left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYuv8/4/

Comment: I believe this is the only way to go.  I think the goal in deprecating align="center" was to prevent the centering of text from affecting the position of a DOM object in the flow.

Comment: Nice, but not very cross-browser compatible. The results aren't identical in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: @PaulSheldrake The alignment in the table cells. In [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFMyn/3/), the text in the table is left aligned; in [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/NYuv8/), centered.

Comment: I've done some more testing, and it's really only the tables that need special care. The other block elements all behave nicely in a centered div. And `<div align="center">` itself also doesn't behave the same across browsers, so there's really not much more we can do.

Answer (score 2):

```
div {width:400px; text-align: center;}
table {display:inline-block;}​
```

Should work as well in addition to Paul's answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/KFMyn/13/

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware that giving the table a different display value would keep the layout inside it intact. I mean, I always assumed that the `<tr>`s would start behaving as if they weren't inside a table at all. That is worth experimenting with a bit! But still, your answer doesn't yield the exact same result as the original code in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ah, you're right - the table's content is also centered. I have overlooked that. Normally I'd use auto margins TBH.  A simple `td {text-align:left; }` should fix it, though.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that put you on an endlessly extending path of ever increasing levels of fine tuning your CSS? I mean, my jsFiddle was only a small example, but what if you have a `<blockquote>` inside the `<div>`? Then you'd have to put in an extra line of CSS to handle that. Etcetera. But I kind of hoped that there would be a real, finite solution, something that you knew would work as a 100% accurate alternative to that align attribute. That's what my question is after.

Comment: Oh, I see I still had `div > * { margin: 0 auto; }` in my test page. Sorry. Now I took that out, things with margins of their own no longer are a problem. So it's really only the tables that cause trouble. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {width:400px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
div > * { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Works for me. But this may not work properly when you have multiple nested dom elements

Comment: And will have no effect on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: But it doesn't really matter. Absolute positioning wasn't a concern brought up by the OP so no need to worry about it.

Comment: @Purmou Sorry, but I meant my question to be more general than just applying to my little example. So absolute positioning does count.

Comment: @pduersteler Your solution almost works on jsFiddle, but jsFiddle does have this massive reset stylesheet that sets all margins to 0. In a real world situation (where `<p>` and `<ul>` do have vertical margins) you should write `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto`. But that leaves the matter of the alignment in the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
```

Above Code might not be working when you are using bootstrap grids.
Here is the quick solution for this using bootstrap 4 and **IT WORKS IN EVERY BROWSERS**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
     <div class="customClass mx-auto">
         <p class="text-center"> your text goes here </p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div
```

you can put any column like col-sm-2, 3, 4.......12

### Replacement for Center tag in different situations

**1. text-center**
Works with p, a, button, h tags and more i.e all the tags containing data or text directly

**2. Flex**
 It can used to align complete element inside another element, however it has more utilities check documentation for reference

Use can center elements using flex in following manners

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

Another import property is flex-direction i.e

```
flex-direction:column
flex-direction:row
```

Use flex direction according to the type of alignment you want

**3. mx-auto (bootstrap class)**

Comment: Using bootstrap, adding "text-center" to the class of an <h4> changes nothing.

Comment: Check in dom if styles are applied, also it does not work if h4 is not a block element taking full width of it's parent.

Comment: For the <H4>, I had to add a container <DIV> and add 'text-center' to its class list - adding to the <H4> directly did not work.  For an <input> tag, I could use 'text-center' in the actual element's class list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and style the table as well, like this:

```
div {
    width:400px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
div table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave it 
    `<div align="center">` 
It still works just fine with all browsers as far as I know. I have plenty of old html and I got to this thread only because my NetBeans IDE is warning me this is obsolete. My guess is the browsers are automatically translating to the correct solution. Same thing with 
    `<font size="6">bla bla</font>` 
still works just fine and probably automatically converted to 
    `<span style="font-size:36px">bla bla</span>`

Comment: Sure it still works, but formally, constructs like that may stop working at any time. Besides, those things don't work the same way in all browsers. See my own pages about [obsolete elements](http://examples.strictquirks.nl/errors/obsolete-elements.php) and [obsolete attributes](http://examples.strictquirks.nl/errors/obsolete-attributes.php) for some examples of differences you can expect. Differences that don't exist when you use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
div { width: 400px; text-align: center; }
table { display: inline-block; }
```

This should work. Check example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ye7ngd3q/2/

and if you want elements inside table cell left/right aligned then you can define individual classes and assign to element respectively as show below:

**HTML**

```
<div align="center">
   A centered div
   <p>A</p>
   <table border="1">
     <tr><td class="align-left">centered</td><tr>
     <tr><td class="align-right">div</td><tr>
   </table>
   <ul><li>A centered div</li></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { width: 400px; text-align: center; }
table { display: inline-block; }
.align-left { text-align: left; }
.align-right { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: Giving a table a different display value has the most horrendous side effects. Besides, it's not necessary at all; see also the accepted answer from 6 years ago.