# Alignment of HTML contents

Tags: html, alignment, center

I have coded buttons and input boxes but I want them to be aligned and placed in the center of the browser, but my output looks messy. I tried using center but the input boxes are not aligned. How do I align them? Thanks in advance.

Here is my complete code:

```
<center>

Name:
<input type="text" id="NameInput">
<br>
Number:
<input type="text" id="NumberInput">    
<br>    
<input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="press(input.value)">
<input type="button" value="EDIT" onClick="press(input.value)">
<input type="button" value="DELETE" onClick="press(input.value)">       
<br><br>
Name:
<input type="text" id="NameSearch">
<br>
Number:
<input type="text" id="NumberSearch">   
<br>    
<input type="button" value="SEARCH" onClick="press(input.value)">           

</center>
```

Comment: Wow, the `<center>` tag. Haven't seen that one in a while.

Comment: The <center> tag is deprecated according to the W3 standards.

Comment: i just want to align my input boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below using margin on a div and specifying a width:

```
<!--ADDED THE BORDER JUST SO YOU CAN SEE WHAT THIS STYLE IS DOING-->
<div style="margin: auto; border: 1px solid red; width: 500px;">
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" id="NameInput">
    </div>

    <div>
        Number: <input type="text" id="NumberInput">    
    </div>

    <div>   
        <input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="press(input.value)">
        <input type="button" value="EDIT" onClick="press(input.value)">
        <input type="button" value="DELETE" onClick="press(input.value)">       
    </div>
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" id="NameSearch">
    </div>
    <div>
        Number: <input type="text" id="NumberSearch">   
    </div>
    <div>   
        <input type="button" value="SEARCH" onClick="press(input.value)">           
    </div>
```

Also take a look at this url: [CSS replacement for <div align="center">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500025/css-replacement-for-div-align-center)

If you want to make all the input boxes align you can try something like below:

```
<Style>
    .label
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 90px;
    }
</style>
<div style="margin: auto; border: 1px solid red; width: 500px;">
    <div>
        <span class="label">Name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="NameInput">
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="label">Number:</span>
        <input type="text" id="NumberInput">    
    </div>

    <div>   
        <input type="button" value="ADD" onClick="press(input.value)">
        <input type="button" value="EDIT" onClick="press(input.value)">
        <input type="button" value="DELETE" onClick="press(input.value)">       
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="label">Name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="NameSearch">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="label">Number: </span>
        <input type="text" id="NumberSearch">   
    </div>
    <div>   
        <input type="button" value="SEARCH" onClick="press(input.value)">           
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements, you could try playing around with the placeholder attribute:

```
    <input type="text" id="NameInput" placeholder="Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<center>` is working properly because it considers the field and the text to be all one line, and it finds the centre of that line. Because the label for each field is a different length, each line has a different centre point.

[How to align input forms in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309950/how-to-align-input-forms-in-html) has a few different approaches. You should use styling to make the label for each field the same length.