# heading tag won't work in alignment attribute

Tags: html

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> my's info </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p align="center">
            <h1>ABOUT ME</h1> 
        </p>
        <p> this is a paragraph  </p>
        <h3> this is a heading </h3>
        <p> this is a paragraph </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

why does not the **ABOUT ME** is not align in the center when i used the heading tag?
does heading tag doesn't work in alignments ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS replacement for <div align="center">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500025/css-replacement-for-div-align-center)

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` tag can only contain inline elements. The header tags are block-level elements, and cannot go inside `<p>` tags even when you style them to display inline.

So in this case your `<h1>` is not considered in your paragraph.
You can see that by adding border attributes to it.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this. heading tags are supposed to mark that as heading and some specific styling by default. center property always works related to div it inside or section.

```html
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> my's info </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <h1>ABOUT ME</h1> 
        </div>
        <p> this is a paragraph  </p>
        <h3> this is a heading </h3>
        <p> this is a paragraph </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the difference between inline and block elements.

```html
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> my's info </title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- Inline element -->
        <p align="center">
            <h1>ABOUT ME</h1> 
        </p>
        <!-- Block element -->
        <div align="center">
            <h1>ABOUT ME</h1> 
        </div>
        <p> this is a paragraph  </p>
        <h3> this is a heading </h3>
        <p> this is a paragraph </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements*

Comment: What do you mean about `inline element`?